# How do I create a chm file with multiple directories via command line?

Tags: chm

I am working on a project where I need to create a chm through command line. It has multiple directories and I was able to get it to work in FAR, which does not have a command line option to create the chm.

Using the MS HTML Help Workshop command:

```
"%programfiles%\HTML Help Workshop\hhc" files.hhp > log.txt
```

where files.hhp looks like:

```
[OPTIONS]
Flat=No

[FILES]
C:\Files\help\index.html
C:\Files\help\page1.html
C:\Files\help\page2.html
C:\Files\help\etc.html
C:\Files\help\pdfs\graph1.pdf
C:\Files\help\pdfs\graph2.pdf
```

I was able to create the chm but it puts the pdf files in the root instead of the pdfs directory in the chm.

According to http://helpware.net/FAR/help/dlg_hhpedit_sec.htm the Flat=No option should fix this but its not having any affect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you change the working dir to c:\files\help before executing?

Explanation: The helpfile compiler probably uses the working directory as root to reduce global paths like "c:\files\help..." to paths relative (to the future .CHM root).